# In PostgreSQL, how can I calculate lexeme frequencies per document for a restricted list of lexemes?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

For the sake of this exposition, I have a list of 10 pre-defined lexemes. In my PostgreSQL database, I have a table where each row has a tsvector column.

How can I determine, for each of the tsvectors, the frequencies (number of occurrences) of only the lexemes in my list of 10? (This sounds like `ts_stat`, except that 1) I need the stats per document and 2) I need it only for the lexemes in my list.)

Intuitively, I would want to calculate `ts_stat` per document, `JOIN`ed with my list of words, but `ts_stat` was really designed to be applied to a `SELECT` resulting in a group of documents.

In the mean time, I've made some progress with a minimal example:

```
create table tsv_test (tsv tsvector, document_id int, freqs jsonb);
-- populated with some documents and tsvectors
create temp table lexemes (word text, ndoc int, nentry int);
-- calculate word frequencies over groups of documents
insert into lexemes select * from ts_stat('select tsv from tsv_test') ORDER BY nentry DESC LIMIT 10;
```

For example, I can now easily go through the table and set its `freqs` column to the json representation of the current document_id:

```
UPDATE tsv_test SET freqs =
(select to_json(document_id))::jsonb
where tsv_test.document_id IN (1,2,3);
```

But let's say I want to populate `freqs` with the `ts_stat` information *per-document* (the JOIN works to show only frequencies of words that are in the document and in the lexemes table):

```
UPDATE tsv_test SET freqs = 
(select array_to_json(array_agg(row)) from (select ts_stat.word, ts_stat.nentry from lexemes JOIN ts_stat('select tsv from tsv_test where document_id=???') ON lexemes.word =     ts_stat.word ORDER BY ts_stat.nentry DESC) row)::jsonb
where tsv_test.document_id IN (1,2,3);
```

What should the `ts_stat` inner SQL query be to accomplish this, seeing that the `UPDATE` is already traversing the set of documents I need to update?

Comment: The closest thing in postgres' full text search (which can achieve that) is `ts_debug()`, but that works from the document itself (not from the `tsvector`) -- and it exists primarily for debugging purposes http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-debugging.html

Answer (score 2):

After much experimentation, this seems to do the trick:

```
UPDATE tsv_test SET freqs = 
  (select array_to_json(array_agg(row)) from 
    (select ts_stat.word, ts_stat.nentry from lexemes
     JOIN ts_stat('select tsv from tsv_test where document_id=' || tsv_test.document_id) ON lexemes.word = ts_stat.word 
    ORDER BY ts_stat.nentry DESC) row)::json
where tsv_test.document_id IN (1,2,3);
```

The `JOIN` ensures that only counts of words that appear in the `lexemes` table are shown. The `UPDATE` stores the results of the per-document word counts in each document as a json field, and the `ts_stat` inner query has to use the string concatenation `|| tsv_test.document_id` so that it only counts the words of the current document.